# how to use sass for next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, node-sass, typescript-eslint

I making Next.js project for tyepscript

i tried install sass

but error occered

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: 
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.
```

add inclued project `next.config.js`

but error no fix

my `.eslintrc.js` code there

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    project: [
      './tsconfig.json'
    ],
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility': 'off',
    'indent': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': ['error', 2],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion': 'error',
    'eol-last': ['error', 'always'],
    'func-style': ['error', 'expression', {
      allowArrowFunctions: true
    }],
    'newline-before-return': 'error',
    'no-dupe-class-members': 'error',
    'no-var': 'error',
    'object-shorthand': ['error', 'always'],
    'prefer-arrow-callback': 'error',
    'prefer-const': 'error',
    'prefer-spread': 'error',
    'require-yield': 'error'
  },
};
```

As long as you look at the formula, it seems to be working without problems, and I think that eslint is the cause, but hasn't solved the problem, is there anyone who knows about this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using createDefaultProgram: true can be the temporary solution in parserOptions until next release.

```
parserOptions:  {
    ...,
    createDefaultProgram: true,        
},
```

And it is known issue.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/967

Comment: That same thread now explicitly warns not to use this hack: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/967#issuecomment-539091676